# Pagination in CouchDB using variable keys

Tags: couchdb

There's a bunch of questions on here related to pagination using CouchDB, but none that quite fit what I'm wondering about.

Basically, I have a result set ranked by number of votes, and I want to page through the set in descending order.

Here's the `map` for reference.

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.votes);
}
```

Now, the problem. I found out that `startkey_docid` doesn't work on it's own. You have to use it in combination with `startkey`. The thing is, for the query, I don't use a `startkey` parameter (I'm not looking to restrict the results, just get the most->least). I was thinking I could just use startkey={{doc.votes}}&startkey_docid={{doc._id}} instead, but the number of votes for a document could have changed by the time someone clicks the "Next Page" link.

The way to solve this seemed obvious: just set `startkey=99999999` so that it will return all documents in the database and I can just use `startkey_docid` to start at the one where we left off last time. Oddly, when I do that, the `startkey_docid` stopped working and just allowed all results to be returned again. Apparently `startkey` needs to exactly equal the key on the document whose `_id` is used in `startkey_docid`.

What I'm asking is whether anyone knows a workaround for using `startkey_docid` to page when the actual `startkey` could have changed by the time you want to use it? Should my application just lookup the document by `_id` and immediately use the `doc.votes` value hoping it hasn't changed in the few milliseconds between requests? Even that doesn't seem very reliable.

EDIT: Ended up switching to Mongo for the speed, so this question turned out to be kinda moot.

Answer (score 1):

I have never done something like this but I think I have some idea how to do it. What you can do is to take a snapshot of the ratings and refer to it in every page. You probably want your view not to consume to much space, so you should not map separate copies of the documents with votes not changed after taking the snapshot. So, you can do the following:

1. Add some history of ratings with timestamp to your document.
2. Map the ratings AND history like this.
3. In your app get the current time: `start_time = Date.now()` and query all pages.
4. Cleanup the history older then the oldest active sessions.

The problem is that if you emit `[votes, date]` and try to paginate you will never know how many document you have to fetch to get desired number per page. There can always be some older version which you will have to skip, and you will have make next get from DB. Thats why you can consider emitting: `[date, votes]`, read the view always twice -- for `start_time` and current time, and merge and sort the result (like in merge-sort).

Ad.1:

```
{ ...,
  votes: 12,
  history: [
    {date: 1357390271342, votes: 10},
    {date: 1357390294682, votes: 11}
  ]
}
```

Ad.2:

```
function (doc) {
  emit([{}, doc.votes], null);
  doc.history && doc.history.forEach(function(h) {
    emit([h.date, h.votes], null);
  });
}
```

Ad.3:

```
?startkey=[start_time, votes]&limit=items_per_page_plus1
?startkey=[{}, votes]&limit=items_per_page_plus1
```

Merge lists, sort by `votes` in your app (on in a list function).
If you will have problems with using `start_docid` then you can emit `[date, votes, id]` and query with the ID explicitly. Even when this particular doc changes its `votes` it will still be available in the history.

Ad.4:
If you emit `[date, votes]` then you can just get outdated history width: `?startkey=[0]&endkey=[oldest_active_session_time]&inclusive_end=false` and update them with [update handler](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers):

```
function(doc, req) {
  if (!doc || !doc.history) return [null, 'Error'];
  var history = new Array();
  var oldest = +(req.query.date);
  doc.history.forEach(function(h) {
    if (h.date >= oldest)
      history.push(h);
  });
  doc.history = history;
  return [doc, 'OK'];
}
```

Note: I have not tested it, so it is expected not to run without modifications :)

As far as I know CouchDB uses b-tree shadowing to make updates and in principle is should be possible to access older revisions of the view. I am not into the CouchDB design, so it is just a guess and there seems not to be any (documented) API for this.

Comment: Actually I do not sure that your answer is correct, but you do the great job and that should be noticed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out any *simple* solution by now, but there are options:

- Replicate not-so-often your sorting list to small dedicated db so it will be much more stale than stale=ok
- Modify your schema in a way that you'll be able to sort by some more stable data. Look at the banking/ledger example in CouchDb guide: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/recipes.html#banking. Try to log every vote and reduce them hourly for example. As a bonus you'll get a history/trends :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of surprised this question has been left unanswered because the functionality of CouchDB Futon basically does this when you are paginating through the results of a map function. I opened up firebug to see what was happening in the javascript console as I paginated and saw that for every set of paginated results it is passing the startkey along with startkey_docid. So although the question is how do I paginate without including startkey, CouchDB specifies that the startkey is required and demonstrates how it can work. The endkey is not specified, so if there is only one result for the specified startkey, the next set of paginated results will also contain the next key of the sorted results that do not match the startkey.

So to clarify a bit, the answer to this problem is that as you are paginating and keeping track of the startkey_docid, you also need to capture the startkey of the same document that will be the start of the next set of results. When you are calling the paginated results use both the captured startkey and startkey_docid as couchdb requires. Leave endkey off so that the results will continue on to the next key of the sorted results.

The usecase scenario for wanting to be able to paginate without specifying a key is kind of odd. So let's say that the start docid of the next paginated result did change it's key value drastically from a 9 to a 3. And we are also assuming that there is only one instance of the docid existing in the map results, even though it could potentially appear multiple times (which I believe is why the startkey needs to be specified). As the user is clicking the next button, the user's paginated results will have now moved from looking at rank 9 to rank 3. But if you are including the startkey in addition to the startkey_docid, the paginated results would just start all over at the beginning of the rank 9 results which is a more logical progression than potentially jumping over a large set of results.